# In command-line, custom text and background colors by directory

Tags: command-line

When in command-line, I need to set custom text and background colors by directory. Example:

```
cd /home/someuser/Documents [ENTER] # I have black text white background
cd /home/someuser/Public [ENTER]  #I have white text on black background
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 15):

One solution is to overwrite `cd` with a function.

Let us say that I saved the function in a file named `cd` at the `$HOME`.  Now I can start using it by `$ source cd` and then `$ cd ~/Documents` etc.

[image]

```bsh
function cd(){

    builtin cd "$@";

    case "$PWD" in

    "$HOME/Documents")
        echo -ne "\033]10;#000000\007"
        echo -ne "\033]11;#FFFFFF\007"
      ;;
    "$HOME/Public")
        echo -ne "\033]10;#FFFFFF\007"
        echo -ne "\033]11;#000000\007"
      ;;
    *)
        # Any other place
        echo -ne "\033]10;#FFFFFF\007"
        echo -ne "\033]11;#000000\007"
      ;;
    esac
}
```

---

Note that you can omit the `$HOME/Public` part because `# Any other place` would handle it anyway. I just leave it there as a reference so you can add any other color if you like.

Comment: `pushd` and plenty of other options would confuse this.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. I only considered `cd` as OP suggested.